# What is this thing found in my saliva?

Tags: microscopy, cell-sorting

Found in my saliva [image] 
(Optical microscope 40x)

Comment: Just to make sure, since you have a lot of external objects in the field of view: are you sure that it's part of the sample and not some dirt on the microscope?

Comment: I don't think so, we cleaned everything before, and it seems to have a nucleus